# spring boot get file and list of objects from response

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, request

I need to get file and list of objects from one post-request. Here is something I did:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
                               @RequestBody ElementsParsePatternWrapperDTO parsingOrder)
```

ElementsParsePatternWrapperDTO:

```
public class ElementsParsePatternWrapperDTO {
private List<ElementParsePatternDTO> patterns;

List<ElementParsePatternDTO> getPatterns() {
    return patterns;
}

public void setPatterns(List<ElementParsePatternDTO> patterns) {
    this.patterns = patterns;
}
```

ElementParsePatternDTO (only constructor):

```
 public ElementParsePatternDTO(PresetsEnum preset) {
    elementParsePattern = FactoryPresetsElementParsePattern.getPreset(preset);
}
```

So, how can I put in json request both list of objects and file? Also, I need to use ajax

Answer (score 0):

In your question you asked about get, but request method has parameters, so I suppose you need to upload file along with some data.
You can use named parameters of form data with json encoded dto param. e.g.

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
public ResponseEntity saveWithFile(@RequestParam("data") String parsingOrderJson, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    ElementsParsePatternWrapperDTO dto = new Gson().fromJson(parsingOrderJson, ElementsParsePatternWrapperDTO.class);
}
```

Maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

But it seems like a not very good practice. Keep it simple.